how to extract file type path and base64 from image upload and send in API call
So I am using Google Gemini API and I am trying to test out in EchoAPI a VSCODE extension similar thing like POSTMAN with same interface. I want to Generate text from text-and-image input REST API method text. My text from text only input is working correct if you see in the documentation to send image in api call three things are required first the image file type second the path of image and third is base64encoding of image when I enter these thing and send request it always give me error
{
    "error": {
        "code": 400,
        "message": "Invalid value at 'contents[0].parts[1].inline_data.data' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"data:image/jpeg;base64,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\"",
        "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
                "fieldViolations": [
                    {
                        "field": "contents[0].parts[1].inline_data.data",
                        "description": "Invalid value at 'contents[0].parts[1].inline_data.data' (TYPE_BYTES), Base64 decoding failed for \"data:image/jpeg;base64,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\""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
}

see here is my JSON payload
{
  "contents": [
    {
      "parts": [
        {
          "text": "what do you see in this image"
        },
        {
          "inline_data": {
            "mime_type": "test/jpeg",
            "data": "data:image/jpeg;base64,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"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}


can anybody tell me how to fix this error and get the response generated from API how to exactly fix this base64 encoding and path error
enter image description here
so I am expecting some this type of output just like this tutorial he get response in object json in candidates[0].parts[0].text like this way I want in EchoAPI POSTMAN
